# Playframework 2.1 and Heroku update problems

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.1, heroku-postgres

i've create a play framework 2.1.0 project and deployed it on heroku. Last friday I've had to change the data models to add some extra fields. Once i tried to deploy the changes, it gave me evolution errors.

Unable to fixe the problem i've reverted the changed and deployed the old version but i still get an error.

The current error i'm getting is this

```
 database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql: ...
 Position: 27 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42601]
 ERROR: syntax error at or near "FALSE"
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:435)
Oops, cannot start the server.
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:434)
at play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.evolutionScript(Evolutions.scala:306)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:63)
at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:62)
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:432)
@6ele4bdao: Database 'default' is in inconsistent state!
....
```

To deploy i'm using the following using this procfile line:

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${POSTGRESQL_URL}
```

Also as suggested i've used `heroku pg:psql` along with `SELECT id, last_problem FROM play_evolutions;` to find out the error and it says `syntax error at or near "FALSE"` but i don't see any false in my 1.sql file.

Anyone can give me a hand with this it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- Your evolution script is wrong, you should test it against a local postgresql database in your dev environment
- You mention that you already did a deployment before. That means that evolution was run already. But you also mention that you are checking for errors inside `1.sql`. If you already run evolutions once, Play would expect the new scripts to be in `2.sql`. This may be a reason you are getting the exception.

Another solution is to disable evolutions (set `evolutionplugin=disabled` in `application.conf`) and do the changes manually by connecting to the postgresql database via a client. It may mean extra work, but it is probably a safer alternative to avoid leaving the database in an unstable state. Sometimes, control is better than automatization.

Comment: Tks for the help. Should the 2.sql be generate automatically or should i rename the 1.sql generated? I didn't get any running locally. Also i tested on my local postgresql and it worked. So I've ended up using the manually option and deleting the tables

Comment: you should create a new file, so you have 1.sql and 2.sql. Play won't generate evolution files automatically, you have to create them.

Comment: how to test an evolution locally?