# Cannot connect to Heoku Postgres Server during Heroku deployment for Play Framework 2.2.3

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.2

I am trying to deploy a Play 2.2.3 application on Heroku using the free database option.

I can successfully deploy the application from new, but when I try to push a new version to Heroku, the app crashes and I get the following error in the logs.

This is quite annoying as currently the only way to update my application is to delete it and push again.

I've looked at some other answers:

[Playframework 2.1 and Heroku update problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271669/playframework-2-1-and-heroku-update-problems)
This suggests that play is looking for a new evolutions file, i.e. 2.sql. I created this file and placed it in the same directory as 1.sql, but it made no difference. I doubt this is the problem though, because I can see in the logs that it is reading the evolutions file.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/F08kemIhQeg/detLnB46mnMJ 
This suggests that the DATABASE_URL is out of date. I've checked it, and this is not the case.

```
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.448124+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m [?[33mwarn?[0m] play - Run
 with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true and -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true if y
ou want to run them automatically, including downs (be careful, especially if yo
ur down evolutions drop existing data)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.447359+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.453487+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:507)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.453523+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:461)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.452965+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m @6ippgoci9: Database 'defa
ult' needs evolution!
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454019+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at scala.collection.immu
table.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.453976+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:459)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.452755+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m Oops, cannot start the ser
ver.
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.453419+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.s
cala:478)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454184+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454084+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454251+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454115+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454052+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:459)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454487+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at scala.Option.map(Opti
on.scala:145)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454286+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.utils.Threads$.w
ithContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454318+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.Play$.start(
Play.scala:87)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454485+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454511+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454152+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at scala.collection.immu
table.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454357+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.core.StaticAppli
cation.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454421+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454217+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454389+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:01.454541+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
?[36m2014-07-17T02:03:57.456589+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m Starting process with c
ommand `target/universal/stage/bin/publicapp -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutio
ns.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DAT
ABASE_URL}`
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:02.728942+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m State changed from star
ting to crashed
?[36m2014-07-17T02:04:02.718630+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m Process exited with sta
tus 255
```